# How is prototype related to other patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, prototype, cloning

I am currently learning the design patterns, I know that Prototype is a creational design pattern.

For my school, I need find how Prototype is related to other design patterns.

Other than it creating (cloning) object, which is related to the other Creational patterns.
Are there any other relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best resource for answering is the book ["Design patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) (AKA "The gang of four"):

- Prototype has many of the same consequences that Abstract Factory and Builder have: it hides the concrete product classes from the client, thereby reducing the number of names clients know about. Moreover, these patterns let a client work with application-specific classes without modification.
- Factory Method often produces a hierarchy of Creator classes that parallels the product class hierarchy. The Prototype pattern lets you clone a prototype instead of asking a factory method to make a new object. Hence you don't need a Creator class hierarchy at all.